# Cypress.io - read inputs from file to use in search form test

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

This is my first post on here so play nice :). The following is part of a cypress.io test that will cycle through different search terms against the onsite search.

Is there a better way to do this than coding each search term on each individual line? I've tried finding a way of reading in from a csv file or defining an array but not had any joy in doing this.

```
cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('Apple')
cy.get('.keepheight > .syns-finder > .search-input--wrapper > .btn').click()
cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('{selectall}{del}')

cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('Apricots')
cy.get('.keepheight > .syns-finder > .search-input--wrapper > .btn').click()
cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('{selectall}{del}')

cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('Apricot')
cy.get('.keepheight > .syns-finder > .search-input--wrapper > .btn').click()
cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('{selectall}{del}')

cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('Bananas')
cy.get('.keepheight > .syns-finder > .search-input--wrapper > .btn').click()
cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('{selectall}{del}')
```

etc. etc.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do in one test suite (adapted)

```js
describe('my tests', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
  });

  ['Apples', 'Apricot', 'Banana'].forEach((item, index) => {

    it(`should handle this fruit '${item}'`, () => {
      cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type(item)
      cy.get('.keepheight > .syns-finder > .search-input--wrapper > .btn').click()
      cy.get('#heroSearchTextForm').type('{selectall}{del}')        
    });

  })
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to read `['Apples', 'Apricot', 'Banana']` from a file?